# Jboss EAP 6.4 domain mode - trouble with console.log output

Tags: redhat, console.log, jboss-eap-6

I have a couple of servers running JBoss EAP 6.4 in domain mode, and I'm having issues with the console.log file. No matter what I do, outputs DEBUG from every server group, making the file grow rapidly.

I've tried, from the console, but no luck so far:

```
/profile=*profile-name*/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:remove-handler(name=CONSOLE)
```

Every single logger and handler in domain.xml / web console is set to INFO as minimum. It seems to be controlled from the startup scripts.

Redhat knowledgebase is not very helpful on the matter either. I'm thinking about editing the startup script and avoid the file creation, but there must be a way cleaner way.

Example logs:

```
[Server:xxxxxxx] 2023-01-17 12:35:55 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:242 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'SessionFactory'
[Server:xxxxxxx] 2023-01-17 12:36:00 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:294 - ConnectionID:4 created by (SQLServerDriver:4)
[Server:xxxxxxx] 2023-01-17 12:36:00 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:980 - ConnectionID:4 This attempt server name: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx port: 1433 InstanceName: null useParallel: false
[Server:xxxxxxx] 2023-01-17 12:36:00 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:984 - ConnectionID:4 This attempt endtime: 1673955375008
[Server:xxxxxxx] 2023-01-17 12:36:00 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:985 - ConnectionID:4 This attempt No: 0
[Server:xxxxxxx] 2023-01-17 12:36:00 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:1300 - ConnectionID:4 Connecting with server: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx port: 1433 Timeout slice: 15000 Timeout Full: 15
```

Those DEBUG messages are not coming out on the server group dedicated log.

Comment: Do you have an example of a log message?

Comment: Sure, edited the main message.

Comment: This pattern looks different than the default meaning your deployment might have a logging configuration file in it.

Comment: Do you mean that one of the deployments is altering the whole console.log output of the server? Thanks!

Comment: You were right, James. It was one of the deployed wars by our developers that sets the entire output to DEBUG. I removed it and now its working as expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad you were able to find it.